# Compare two tables for difference and output to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table A contains information about a list of files.

[image]

I have another table B contains information about the same list of files, but `LastModifyTime` may changed.

[image]

Now I want to Compare these two tables, find all differences and input into Table C. There are chances new files exist in Table B but Table A. I could use

```
SELECT * FROM Table B

EXCEPT

SELECT * FROM Table A
```

It only gives me a list of differences. but I want Table C looks like this, contains both data from Table A and Table B on differences of LastModifyDate.

How can I do it? `left join` ?

Note: I need to have the result of comparison written into Table C. not just as a result of query.

[image]

Comment: you just need a join with a filter on unequal dates from the tables.

Comment: @RootLoop . . . What if files exist in "A" but not "B"?

Comment: Could be @GordonLinoff

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `Outer JOIN` with `Source_Last_Modify_Date` from `tableA` not equal to `Source_Last_Modify_Date` from `tbaleb`.

```
SELECT a.Source_File_Name,
       a.Source_Creation_Date,
       a.Source_Last_Modify_Date 'Source_Last_Modify_Date_From_Table_A',
       b.Source_Last_Modify_Date 'Source_Last_Modify_Date_From_Table_B'
FROM [Table B] b 
LEFT JOIN [Table A] a 
ON a.Source_File_Name = b.Source_File_Name 
AND a.Source_Creation_Date = b.Source_Creation_Date
AND b.Source_Last_Modify_Date <> a.Source_Last_Modify_Date
```

Comment: ok, what about if file exist in B but not in A? it wont be the case of `a.name=b.name AND a.create=b.create`  How can I output the query results to Table C?

Comment: What's your expect to result from your case? and what's `query results to Table C?` mean?

Comment: I need a 3rd table contains the result of comparison between table A and B, not only existing file, but also newly created file. I scan a lot of files in a folder, lets say today i will feed table a and tomorrw I will feed table b, tomorrow there may have files been modified or newly created, so table b may contain new file records. so `a.name=b.name` may be not covering all cases.

Comment: `To table C` meaning the result of comparison will be written into Table C

Comment: I guess you can try to use  `LEFT JOIN` or `FULL JOIN` to get your result

Comment: `Left join` and `full join` returned me 480 records, I only have 24 records in both table...

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to use the MINUS command to me. See http://www.sqltutorial.org/sql-minus/

Answer (score 0):

Just little bit change in above answer because of question statement
"There are chances new files exist in Table B but Table A."

```
SELECT b.Source_File_Name,
         b.Source_Creation_Date,
         a.Source_Last_Modify_Date 'Source_Last_Modify_Date_From_Table_A',
         b.Source_Last_Modify_Date 'Source_Last_Modify_Date_From_Table_B'
  FROM [Table B] b 
  LEFT JOIN [Table A] a 
  ON b.Source_File_Name = a.Source_File_Name 
  AND b.Source_Creation_Date = a.Source_Creation_Date
  AND b.Source_Last_Modify_Date <> a.Source_Last_Modify_Date
```

Might be it will helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you also want to account for file deletion, then you need a `FULL JOIN` or similar mechanism.  Filtering on `FULL JOIN` is tricky:

```
SELECT COALESCE(a.Source_File_Name, b.Source_File_Name) as Source_File_Name,
       COALESCE(a.Source_Creation_Date, b.Source_Creation_Date) as Source_Creation_Date,
       a.Source_Last_Modify_Date as Source_Last_Modify_Date_From_Table_A,
       b.Source_Last_Modify_Date as Source_Last_Modify_Date_From_Table_B
FROM [Table B] a FULL JOIN
     [Table A] b
     ON b.Source_File_Name = a.Source_File_Name AND
        b.Source_Creation_Date = a.Source_Creation_Date
WHERE a.Source_File_Name IS NULL OR
      b.Source_File_Name IS NULL OR
      b.Source_Last_Modify_Date <> a.Source_Last_Modify_Date;
```